# Options to mitigate espionage/tracking possibilities

Tags: privacy

Which options exist in (stock/custom) firmware to mitigate smartphone espionage/tracking possibilities? I talk about things like:

- Disable/use random mac/do not leak ssid on active WLAN probing
- Warn on/do not acknowledge silent/type-0 SMS
- etc.

I don't want to use root requiring apps which tinker with the WLAN/3G/4G stack to disable such useless and possible dangerous "features" of my phone.

Comment: A very interesting question indeed, and I'd really like to see answers to it! Unfortunately, asking for off-site resources is off-topic here. Would it fit your intention to rephrase it a little, as I just did now, so it can stay on this site? Answers are still allowed to "point outside" if needed.

Comment: **CLOSE VOTERS:** Note the edit. It's no longer asking for off-site resources (ROMs etc), so the question should be legit here (asking for privacy-related configuration options and how to use them).

Comment: Really strict rules here. Thanks for editing!

Comment: We have to. You've got no idea what we'd otherwise be drowning in :) Btw: If you receive an answer, I'd be thankful for a ping (which I'd receive if you address me directly in a comment on this question like `@Izzy` – or in chat, as soon as you've got 20+ rep :)